# how to make solr unavailable to users before full dataset is updated to solr?

Tags: solr, restore

I'm using solr (standalone mode) as data lookup service. It takes the application about 20 minutes to update full dataset to solr. I wanted the solr instance to not available to use until full dataset is updated.

One way I can think of is to use another solr instance (B) to make the full dataset updated, backup the index data and then restore the index to the solr instance (A) that user uses. However the problem is that to restore index, I need to start solr(A) so there will still some gap between when solr(A) is started and when solr(A) restored full index. Is there a way to restore index data before starts solr instance?

Answer (score 1):

Don't query the same index that you're updating. You don't need multiple servers; what you need is two collections that you switch between.

If you were using cloud mode, you [could use an alias that points to the updated collection](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/aliases.html). You index to `collection_x`, then change the `collection` alias to point to `collection_x` when you're ready. Next time you index to `collection_y`, then change the alias to point to `collection_y` when you're done, and then remove old collections as necessary later (use a timestamp/date instead of characters).

When you're using Solr in the standalone mode you don't have aliases available as far as I remember, but you can perform core swaps. This allows you to index all your content to a separate core, and when you're done, you just swap the names of the two cores - any requests coming in after that goes to the new core (which has now been renamed).

If you have `core` and `core_indexing`, you can then call `admin/cores?action=SWAP&core=core&other=core_indexing` when you're done with indexing. This is an atomic operation, so neither core will have any downtime.

Next time you're indexing, index to `core_indexing` as usual - clean it out first, then index the new content, commit and call `SWAP` again, swapping the new content in. No downtime, no hacking around to have to restore indexes from a replication standpoint (which you could probably work around by issuing a RELOAD instead, and swapping the directories .. but don't do that, use the existing support for this instead).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However this is not what I want. What I want is that user either query the full dataset, or solr is offline.

Comment: Add authentication and disable it when you're done indexing? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html

Comment: .. or use a random, long core name, then rename it when it should become available. That will generate 404-s until it's actually available.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be which we had done for our application.
Maintain the list of core you created in the database and add status column to it.

When you have not done with full indexing have the status as offline. Once the indexing is in progress then make the status as inProgress.

Once you complete the indexing and make it available for searching then change the status to Searchable.

Here every core can be maintained with its own status.